# Getting data from MYSQL into JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following quite simple test PHP code that extracts the data and puts it into JSON formatted text.

I get the following error..

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1979603 bytes) in /var/www/test.php on line 33

Where line 33 is the `json_encode()` line.

Is there a way to make this more efficient?  The `PHP.ini` is already set to 32M as max, hence sized up from the 8M standard!

```
 <?php
    require('../../admin/db_login.php');

    $db=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $db) or die('');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from listinfo") or die('Could not query');
    $json = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            //  cast results to specific data types

            $test_data[]=$row;
        }
        $json['testData']=$test_data;
    }

    mysql_close($db);

    echo json_encode($json);


    ?>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are probably encoding a very large dataset. You could encode each row, one row at a time instead of encoding it in one big operation.

```
<?php
require('../../admin/db_login.php');

$db=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db) or die('');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from listinfo") or die('Could not query');

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    echo '{"testData":[';

    $first = true;
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        //  cast results to specific data types

        if($first) {
            $first = false;
        } else {
            echo ',';
        }
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
    echo ']}';
} else {
    echo '[]';
}

mysql_close($db);
```

That way, each call to `json_encode()` only encodes a small array instead of a large one. The end result is the same. **This is IMO the solution which will use the less memory.**

Comment: @Lee: Unconventional, but that way you don't have to store every row into an array for later encoding.

Comment: Is there anyway to get it to put the row header on each one?

Comment: @Lee: To have `"testData"` on every row? Yes, but why would you want that? That's not how your original code behaved.

Comment: No, to have the column header:column data

Comment: @Lee: Sure! Replace `mysql_fetch_row($result)` with `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` in your while loop.

Answer (score 10):

Stop duplicating your array of data

```
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        //  cast results to specific data types

        $json['testData'][]=$row;
    }
}
```

that will help reduce your memory usage

Comment: Yes good shout!  Didn't realise i was duplicating it there at all!  That has worked with 16 bytes over, setting to 64M now it fits :-)

Answer (score 7):

**Use this one:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listinfo");

$json = array();
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($total_records > 0){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $row;
  }
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Why are you using `if($total_records >= 1){` and `$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);`?

Comment: some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

As a first work-around set it to something like 256M or even 512M.

It is probable the dataset that MySQL is returning to you is quite big. So even if your PHP is very memory-efficient, you still will get the OoM error. So as a more viable long-term solution use the `LIMIT` statement (`SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 0,30` (start from index 0, get 30 items).

EDIT: Oh wow, I didn't even see the problem from the first solution... Well, still might be a good idea to `LIMIT` your query :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first json that works perfectly

```
<?php
// connect to mysql server
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
// select the db name
mysql_select_db($dbname);
    // enter your sql query
    $sql = "Select * from Order_Details";
// Creates temp array variable
$temp = array();
// Gets table details
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// Adds each records/row to $temp
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
// Formats json from temp and shows/print on page
echo json_encode($temp);
?>
```